# Spark:repartition and number of tasks (skipped)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am repartitioning the data frame after reading the data from ORC,

```
Available cores 6
df = spark.read.orc("filePath")
df.rdd.getNumPartitions()

Giving output as 12 partitions ( It is expected job ran locally so ( cores * 2) in my case 6 * 2 = 12)

Now i am increasing the partitions 
df = df.repartition(50)
df.rdd.getNumPartitions() ---- returning 50 partitions
```

When observed in the SparkUI the job is still executing 12 tasks where as 50 tasks stage was skipped

How to tell spark to use 50 tasks instead of 12 default tasks ?.
Even after forcing repartition to 50  , Why spark is still using 12 tasks ? why not 50 tasks. Could you please some one help me here
As seen in below diagram

[Spark Ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTa3w.png)

Comment: concurrently? check how many partitions you have after pls and report back?

Comment: That’s cause you don’t have enough resources, here Threads to run the task

Comment: @thebluephantom df.rdd.getNumPartitions() is returning 50 partitions but in spark UI 50 tasks stage is skipped, only 12 tasks stage is executed

Comment: How to increase the threads ? i have 6 cores machine

Comment: How many record in table?

Comment: 10K records in table

Comment: Title of question is wrong as you observe

Answer (score 0):

I grant you that reading the Spark UI stuff is not always clear. I do not understand it fully at times. I looked on Databricks Community edition a similar case, but not a fair comparison as it is a driver with 8 cores. You do not state your Spark version.

None-the-less: when requesting `repartition(n)` --> this is round robin partitioning. The source is 12 partitions and the target 50 partitions. So the 12 tasks are fine in all ways. You need to go from 12 to 50 partitions, from the existing to the new partitions. 50 + 12 = 62, the skipping I think is the previous not yet returned to system partitions.

Few responses, SO is less popular I believe now.

Comment: Thanks for your response, How i can tell in Spark for single cpu core to handle multiple partitions ?or it is always single cpu for single partition.

Comment: The executor will handle them sequentially. The DAG creates tasks for partitions and they get scheduled. Nothing you need to do, happens automatically. If you agree with answer, pls accept.